# CTest misparsing add_test calls

Tags: cmake, ctest

I am trying to run some tests using CTest.

My `CTestTestFile.cmake` contains a single test

```
add_test(NAME test1 
COMMAND python script.py args
)
```

but when I try run `ctest` it outputs the following

```
Start 1: NAME
Could not find executable test1
Looked in the following places:
test1
test1.exe
Release/test1
Release/test1.exe
Debug/test1
Debug/test1.exe
MinSizeRel/test1
MinSizeRel/test1.exe
RelWithDebInfo/test1
RelWithDebInfo/test1.exe
Deployment/test1
Deployment/test1.exe
Development/test1
Development/test1.exe
Unable to find executable: test1
1/1 Test #1: NAME .............................***Not Run   0.00 sec

0% tests passed, 1 tests failed out of 1

Total Test time (real) =   0.14 sec

The following tests FAILED:
          1 - NAME (Not Run)
```

This suggests CTest thinks I'm using the short version of the command, so that my test's name is `NAME`, the command is `test1` and `python script.py args` are the arguments to the command, when this is of course not the case, as I'm obviously using the long version of the command.

I have CMake version 3.24.1 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CTest runtime, unlike CMake, accepts *only* the "basic" signature documented at the end of the usual [`add_test` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_test.html):

> ```
> add_test(<name> <command> [<arg>...])
> ```

Notice that CTest thought your test was named `NAME`.

So you have to write:

```
add_test(test1 "python" "script.py" "args")
```

Comment: In that case, is there a way to set the working directory for the command to be run?

Comment: Of course. `set_tests_properties(test1 PROPERTIES WORKING_DIRECTORY "whatever")`.

Comment: Note that you might have a better experience generating a `CTestTestfile.cmake` via CMake itself... use `project(myproj-tests LANGUAGES NONE)` to disable all languages, set `enable_testing()` and then you can use the full signature without needing a C/C++ compiler sitting around.